# Automatically Publish Knowledge Article

Tags: trigger, workflow, action, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to implement a requirement where few knowledge articles based on the priority(custom picklist) will be auto published immediately they are getting created.

I am currently doing this with workflow and knowledge action. Tried using the KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle as well in the Trigger, but is this only available for Classic Knowledge and not for Lightning Knowledge?

Also apart from what I am doing, is there any better approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm#apex_KbManagement_PublishingService_publishArticle) is supported for both classic as well as lightning.

You need to pass the `Knowledge__kav.KnowledgeArticleId` field to it and not `Knowledge__kav.Id`.

**Sample code**

```
public class TriggerHandlerOnKnowledge {
    public static void run() {
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
            publishHighPriority((List<Knowledge__kav>)Trigger.new);            
        }
    }

    private static void publishHighPriority(List<Knowledge__kav> articles) {
        for(Knowledge__kav article: articles) {
            if(article.priority__c == 'High') {
                KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(article.KnowledgeArticleId, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was doing. My problem here is that seems like this api is not bulkified. I am not sure what's the impact on Salesforce limit's like DML and all.

Comment: Yes, that's a downside, however, considering real scenario knowledge articles are mostly created by authors one at a time. To be safe you can add an additional check on the size of Trigger.new and delegate the job to a batch class in case of bulk upload.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Anmol

Answer (score -1):

you can use knowledge actions (Workflow field updates) to publish a new version

Comment: OP says he is already using workflow and knowledge action.